# How can I get two SSL certs to work on a two domain, shared IP configuration

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I have two web site that are 99% similar. They share all of the same pages except the difference being that the logos change, a few of the links change, and the products that show up on either web site are flagged to show up on either or, or both. They use the same database.

I have written a utility method that essentially injects a where clause into any database access code I write throughout the app to determine which products to display depending on the current URL.

**Problem:** Website B gives the user a warning message that the site they are trying to go to is in fact Website A. I've read that the SSL cert needs a distinct IP.

Right now how I have everything set up is very clean on a maintenance perspective. I can update files in one place. Any suggestions on how to make the SSL behave, or am I looking at seperate IP's for the hosting(I really don't want to have to do this)?

If the latter, what do you suggest?

Site runs ASP.NET 4.0. Precompiled DLL.

Comment: How does the server know which website to deliver?

Comment: It's two domain names that point to the same files and database. The code reads the url and determines wether to display logo A, or logo B. If it needs to get different database content I have a custom LINQ method that builds a where clause dynamically.

Comment: Unless and Until IIS supports [SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), you'll need to use two distinct IPs (if you're not going down the wildcard/subdomain route)

Comment: I will be using two distinct IPs

Comment: Since it is SSL, the code cannot read the URL until the SSL handshake is completed and the first record is decrypted. But the server certificate must be presented during the handshake. Hence the chicken and egg problem, and @Damien_The_Unbeliever comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: Thanks to @GregS comment

If the sites share the same domain you can use a wildcard certificate

- site1 - site1.somedomain.com
- site2 - site2.somedomain.com

Otherwise you will need to get a UCC (United communications certificate) that will be for both domains.

You will need to configure IIS 7 from the command line because the GUI doesn't support setting different host headers for the same certificate. [This tutorial](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html) shows how it can be done.

Comment: I'm fully aware of wildcard SSL, and in this particular case the client does not want to use sub domains like you have suggested. Anyway to setup another server to inherit the files from another server, so that I only need to maintain one place?

Comment: In this case you'll need 2 certificates and 2 IPs. I don't think there is a way to have 2 certificates on the same IP. At least I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: You can get a certificate with multiple domain names that is not a wildcard certificate.

Comment: I'm looking into a SAN certificate after following marto's link.

Answer (score 0):

I setup another website in IIS that points to the same files as the first web site, got another SSL cert for the new site.